# update variable from ViewController to a view

Tags: swift, delegates

I have a viewController A and a popView B.
1) Click a button from A to pop View B.
2) Click a button from B to a controller C. 
3) Click confirm button from controller C to return a value.

ViewController A has the delegate function that manage 3).

I want to change the button title in 2) after doing action 3).

The code I have now is below:

in ViewController A:

```
var popView: PopView?   //PopView is my popView B
```

in my delegate function I have:

```
self.popView?.pickFromWhereButton.setTitle("\(place.name ?? "NA")", for: .normal).  // pickFromWhereButton is the button in View B
```

However, pickFromWhereButton's title wouldn't change when I finish action 3).

Comment: fast test do `self.popView!.` instead of `self.popView?.` to check nil crash

Answer (score 0):

When you present the vc  from the 1 that contains this function `pickFromWhereButton` don't forget to assign

```
vc.popView = self
```